# Find an integer a which satisfies a ≡ 5 (mod 8) and a ≡ 3 (mod 7)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, congruences

We are learning congurence class part for an intro course. This is a sample exam question without a solution.

I have poor idea about this problem.

My idea is : suppose there is an a satisfies it.

then I have

7a ≡ 35 (mod 56) and 8a ≡ 24 (mod 56)

then by doing the substraction I get

a ≡ -11 (mod 56)

then

a ≡ 45 (mod 56)

That is all the steps I can do up to now.

Any hint plz?

Thank you in advance.

==========

Addition: actually I found it is the correct anwser that a = 45. But I am not really sure why it is the answer. I got this answer suprisingly..

Comment: $45 = 5 \pmod 8$ and $45 = 3 \pmod 7$.

Comment: @fvel Yes it is the anwser but I dont know why it is....

Comment: Well you got that $a\equiv 45\pmod{56}$ hence any $a=56k+45$ is solution to your problem,and you got it on a fine way.

Comment: @kingW3 So I can think [$a$] is a class in $a$ + $56Z$ where $a = 45$, is that right? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the method of adding the modulus to solve a problem like this:

$\pmod{8}: a\equiv 5\equiv 13\equiv 21\equiv 29\equiv 37\equiv 45$.

We note that $45$ also satisfies the $\mod{7}$ congruence.

So the solution is $a\equiv 45\pmod{56}$.

Comment: Thank you. This is an excellent and brief way for small numbers.

Comment: @Son General method is just as easy: solve ${\rm mod}\ 7\!:\,\ \color{#0a0}3\equiv a\equiv \color{#90f}{5}\!+\!\color{blue}8n\equiv 5\!+\!n\iff n\equiv \color{#c00}{-2}\equiv 5,\,$ as in my answer, i.e. $\,\color{blue}{8\equiv 1}\,$ so we must subtract it $\color{#c00}{\rm twice}$ from $\,\color{#90f}5\,$ to get $\,\color{#0a0}3,\,$ Equivalently, we can add it $\,5\,$ times, by $\,-2\equiv 5.\,$ The above answer is simply solving this equation by brute force testing $\,n \equiv 1,2,3.\ldots\,$ It's true that in some cases checking for small solutions can be *much* easier than the general CRT.

Answer (score 3):

${\rm mod}\ 8\!:\,\ a\equiv 5\iff a = \color{#0a0}{5+ 8n}$

${\rm mod}\ 7\!:\,\ 3\equiv a\equiv \color{#0a0}{5+8n}\equiv 5+n\iff n\equiv -2\equiv 5\iff  \color{#c00}{n = 5+7k}$

So we conclude  $\ a = 5+8\color{#c00}n = 5+8(\color{#c00}{5+7k}) = 45 + 56k$

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is gonna help you because this solution may not be one you are looking for, however it just uses very simple idea.

Suppose that 
$$
a \equiv 5 \;\text{(mod 8)} \quad a\equiv 3 \;\text{(mod7)}
$$

Then $a+11$ must be divisible by both $8$ and $7$. So $a+11 \equiv 0 \; \text{(mod $56$)}$.
Which gives unique solution up to mod $56$.